# Makefile : Nothing to be done, but none of the dependency recipes were executed

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have probably done something wrong as this is the first makefile I write. I'm trying to make an executable file in `bin` named `82`, and before that I'm building my "library" `tab.o` after having tested it. For some reason, make only makes and runs the test file, but then doesn't build any of the stuff above ?

I have tried removing the `tabtest` from `build/tab.o` 's prerequisites, as I thought that could be messing up the implicit rule, but then make says `nothing to be done for 'all'`.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -std=c89 -pedantic -O3

all: bin/82

bin/82: src/82/main.c build/tab.o

build/tab.o: src/82/tab.c tabtest

tabtest: src/82/tab.c src/82/tab_test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o bin/test/tab
    bin/test/tab
```

Folder structure :

```
bin/
  test/
build/
src/
  82/
    main.c
    tab.c
    tab.h
    tab_test.c
```

Comment: Well you defined a target `bin/82` and listed some prerequisites, but you didn't give any recipe for how to build the target `bin/82`.  So, as long as the prerequisites exist, there is nothing else for make to do here.

Comment: @MadScientist It seemed to me that bin/82 would be built automatically with the implicit rules, as it has .c and .o prerequisites. Is that not the case ?

Comment: You may call `make` with option [`-d`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary) to see what make is doing and which rules and files it considers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything about make's implicit rules are simple pattern matching.  There's no magical deeper understanding of how compilers work or even what a "compiler" is: either the pattern matches, or it doesn't.

Make has two possible built-in implicit rules for building executables: `%: %.c` and `%: %.o`.  The stem (`%`) must be identical; that's what I mean by "pattern matching".

In your rule: `bin/82 : src/82/tab.c` the stem of the target (what matches the `%`) is `bin/82`, which means that the prerequisite `%.c` must be `bin/82.c` and the prerequisite `%.o` must be `bin/82.o`.  Since those files doesn't exist and make can't find any other rules that could create them, the pattern doesn't match.

Since none of the patterns match, there is no recipe to build that target.  If you renamed your source file from `src/82/main.c` to `bin/82.c` then make's built-in rules would match.  If you don't want to do that, you can't use make's built-in rules and you have to write your own recipe.

Comment: Well it wouldn't make any sense to have a source file in the binaries directory, so I will be using explicit rules.

Comment: You don't have to use explicit rules.  You can't use the built-in pattern rules because that's not how they work.  But you can certainly create your **OWN** pattern rules that work the way you want.